# Can't resolve 'style-loader' webpack 4

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

https://github.com/ViktorNA/BooksProject

When run "build"

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently -r --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  }
Webpack finish work with 9 errors for every .js - file
./client/src/index.js
  11:0  error  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in 'D:\Zona
               Downloads\ITVDN NodeJS\materials\books'
....
./client/src/router.js
  0:0  error  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in 'D:\Zona
              Downloads\ITVDN NodeJS\materials\books'
and 1 warning
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to
                'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or
                'production' to enable defaults for each environment.

.babelrc:
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}

devDepensis:
{
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.10.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack-command": "^0.2.0",
    "webpack-config": "^7.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.2"
  }
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Paste your configuration file

Comment: npm install style-loader

Comment: @TanmoySarkar the package is installed

Comment: Check it says module not found..

Comment: Did you try to delete node-modules folder and npm install again?

Comment: @Raaj Nadar 
const config = {
  entry: './client/src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: '/',
    filename: 'Appbundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.txt$/, use: 'raw-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.css?$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'style-loader'
      }
      ]
  }
]

  }
};

module.exports = config;

Comment: @Stefano Vuerich Yes

Comment: @Raaj Nadar  https://github.com/ViktorNA/BooksProject